# jquery selectable link button issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

i am using Jquery selectable to select student names and these names are hyperlink. it seems that even when i click on them it makes these items seleactable, however what i want is if they click on hyperlink it should postback otherwise if user draw a lesso it should select. any help?

Comment: Can you post an example of code?

Comment: Yes please. You can show (and try) your code here: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

There's a cancel option for this, that defaults to `:input, option`.  jQuery UI [does a `return false` for the click](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.7/ui/jquery.ui.selectable.js#L137) check you click on a selectable element (invoking it's own behavior) *unless* [the target matches the `cancel` selector filter](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.7/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js#L58).

So to get this working, just add `a` to the [`cancel` option selector](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#option-cancel), for example:

```
$(".selector").selectable({ cancel: "a,:input,option" });
```

...if you're sure there are not inputs or `<option>` elements, it can just be `"a"`.